# Scala counter not updating when Akka message is received

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to make a small Akka example work using the following code:

```
class Sender extends Actor {
  @volatile var numEchoes = 0

  def receive = {
    case Echo => {
      numEchoes += 1
      println(numEchoes)
      if(numEchoes < Main.NUMBER_OF_ECHOES) {
        println("Heard an echo...")
      }
      else {
        // all echoes have been received.
        println("All echoes heard.")
        context.system.terminate
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This actor is going to receive `Echo` messages from several `Receiver` actors:

```
class Receiver extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Echo => sender ! Echo
  }
}
```

However, `numEchoes` always prints out `1`. If I was doing something wrong, I'd expect `0`, but this value makes me believe something else is at play here, but I'm unable to figure out what it is.

The rest of the code is just sending this specific actor a certain number of messages (lets assume 10). I see `Heard an echo...` printed out 10 times, but the value of this variable does not change.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you are presenting and should work. The error exists some place else.

Comment: Well... I see 10x the `Heard an echo...`, plus 10 times `1` printed on the console. The else bit is not executed. I'm pretty sure there are 10 messages getting to the actor, so I'd say the error has to be around here. Where else? :/

Comment: Is there a single actor handling requests?

Comment: Yes, I only created one. I'll add the Main code in a few minutes

Comment: Why the var numEchoes  is volatile?

Comment: My first version was without `@volatile`, but I thought that this actor could be handling the same type of message concurrently, and I tried to eliminate that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@wheaties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178060/wheaties) was correct. The error was in the Main object, due to some late and careless copy pasting... When I was creating 1 `Sender` and 10 `Receiver` actors, this is the code I was using:

```
// Create the actor that will send out the messages
val sender = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Sender], "sender")

var actorList = List[ActorRef]()

for(i <- 1 to NUMBER_OF_ECHOES) {
  val receiver = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Sender], "receiver"+i)
  actorList ::= receiver
}
```

Of course, creating the receivers as Senders is completely wrong, so all I had to do was fix the typo and correctly spawn the actors:

```
// Create the actor that will send out the messages
val sender = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Sender], "sender")

var actorList = List[ActorRef]()

for(i <- 1 to NUMBER_OF_ECHOES) {
  val receiver = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Receiver], "receiver"+i)
  actorList ::= receiver
}
```